# Ubuntu authentication via active directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory

I have a bunch of Ubuntu machines and an active directory on Windows server 2012. I would like to setup a centralize authentication from my active directory. Basically, When the user tries to login a Linux computer. The authentication credentials are sent my windows server 2012 for the check. If the user credential is correct, active directory accepts the authentication an user can login Linux computer. Otherwise, the user cannot get access. The goal is to have all user in the same place so that It would be easy to block users in the same place instead of going on every single computer. There are tools like PAM, Kerberos, ... But I don't know to the right direction to take now.

I have never done this but I think it is possible and It could make life easier.

Please give me some tutorial or just idea on how to find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.12.linux.aspx

Comment: There are probably other useful findings in [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+computer+in+active+directory+domain).